# conjunction table and C# class?

Tags: c#, oop, database-design

I have ResorceTopices & Resources tables m to m relationship and conjunction  between the 2 table. Just wondering if should I write class for conjunction or not and if I write one should be like this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BOL
{
    class Topic_Resorsce
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        public int ResorsceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you mapping to-from your database?

Comment: I use BOL and ADO.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you can do it however you prefer but my answer would be no. Your classes should look like this:

```
public class Topic
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     //whatever other fields should exist
     public Resource Resource {get; set; }

}

public class Resource
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     //whatever other fields should exist     
}
```

Now you create a data access layer (or preferrably use an ORM such as EntityFramework (included in .NET), NHibernate, NHydrate, Lightspeed, etc.) that maps between your classes and your database.

Of course, there is plenty of code which has a one-for-one mapping between SQL table and POCO - so it is certainly done, I just wouldn't encourage it.